# Impossible to fetchAll - empty page

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo

I'm trying to do a PDO select that will turn into a table with several rows. I'm just getting an empty page, no error message. Here is my code

```
//variables for connection are stated elsewhere
$pdo_connect = new PDO($dsn, $db_host_admin_username, $db_host_admin_pass);
$pdo_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$pdo_connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);

$sql_property_info_request = "SELECT * FROM property_offered_bid WHERE bid_id_property_offered_bid=:bid_id";
$stmt_property_info_request = $pdo_connect->prepare($sql_property_info_request);
$stmt_property_info_request->execute(['bid_id' => $bid_id]);
$result_property_info_request = $stmt_property_info_request->fetch();   
        
while ($row = $stmt_property_info_request->fetch()) {
    echo $row['property_offered_property_offered_bid']."<br />\n";
}
```

I've searched if it was PDO parameters and nothing seems to solve that.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I've also tried with fetchAll.

Comment: You know this code will always miss out the first result? You call a single `fetch()` just after you `execute()` which will bring the first result, but you don't display it. Then you have another `fetch()` as part of your `while()` loop, which will display second and subsequent results.

Comment: @Firewizz: Thank you for your input. the column name are correct. I reverified them.

Comment: @droopsnoot: I added several other entries with similar parameters, and none show..

Comment: If you do a single `fetchAll()` does it return any results? What about if you put the same query into phpmyadmin?

Comment: Are you using PHP 8? If not, you need to enable PDO error reporting.

Comment: With `FETCH_OBJ` you won't receive an array. `$row['property_offered_property_offered_bid']` should throw an error

Comment: What exactly is the purpose of the while loop? Why not a simple `foreach`?